# How to mock const peer it in jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

There are milion questions about how to mock const inside it test, but no one works.

Can some one provide working solution how to mock `import isNode from 'detect-node';` for `it`? (https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect-node)

My code doesn`t work. Its not mocking` isNode` is always true.

Example:

Test file:

```
import { myTestFn } from './fn'
 
describe(('TEST'), () => {
    it(('node mock false'), () => {
        jest.doMock('detect-node', () => false);
        myTestFn(); // will print constant
    });

    it(('node mock true'), async () => {
        jest.doMock('detect-node', () => true);
        myTestFn(); // will print constant
    });
});
```

Fn file:

```
import isNode from 'detect-node';
export const myTestFn = () => console.log({isNode})
```

Excepted output is:

```
false (for 'node mock false')
true (for 'node mock true')
```

I tried a lot of ways how to do it, using doMock, mock, mock in test, mock outside test,...

I am using "jest": "^26.4.2",

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You should use [jest.resetModules()](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestresetmodules) and dynamic `import('./fn')` after mocking.

> Resets the module registry - the cache of all required modules. This is useful to isolate modules where local state might conflict between tests.

E.g.

`fn.ts`:

```js
import isNode from 'detect-node';

export const myTestFn = () => console.log({ isNode });
```

`fn.test.ts`:

```js
describe('63811749', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
  });
  it('node mock false', async () => {
    jest.doMock('detect-node', () => false);
    const { myTestFn } = await import('./fn');
    myTestFn();
  });

  it('node mock true', async () => {
    jest.doMock('detect-node', () => true);
    const { myTestFn } = await import('./fn');
    myTestFn();
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/63811749/fn.test.ts
  63811749
    ✓ node mock false (13ms)
    ✓ node mock true (2ms)

  console.log src/stackoverflow/63811749/fn.ts:3
    { isNode: false }

  console.log src/stackoverflow/63811749/fn.ts:3
    { isNode: true }

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.749s, estimated 12s
```

Comment: Is there any way how can I do it without direct import of my component in test?

Comment: @nirebam368 Is this a different question? If so, please ask a new question.

Comment: nope, its connected to my question, I am importing in top of the file. Looks like there are some issues while I am importing react component in test `const Home = await import('./home');` I am getting `Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`